# Is there a cleaner way to write this? (Ruby/Rails blocks, return value)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, return-value, block

```
  def find_users_online(count = 1)        
    users = Array.new
    count.times do 
      users += get_users_online
    end
    users # <==== I want to remove this here
  end
```

In the code above im must put the "users" variable again at the end of the function to return the right value (users). But is it possible that the times block return the users values and I can remove "users" at the end of the function?

```
  def find_users_online(count = 1)        
    users = Array.new
    count.times.and_return do # <== something like this
      users += get_users_online
    end
  end
```

Comment: Because it's more readable or intuitive to have your "return indication" four lines before the end of the code? Imagine if your block were 100 lines long, how the hell would you be able to read it?

Comment: Why would you want to call `get_users_online` multiple times?

Comment: @Platinum: if his block were 100 lines long, he'd have bigger problems than this one...  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out #tap. It's the new-fangled way to do "returning".

```
def find_users_online(count = 1)   
  [].tap do |users|
    count.times { users += get_users_online }
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, thats exactly that i'm looking for.
But I must change the += to << that it works in my case

Answer (score 3):

Lavir's solution is good if get_users_online will return the same value very time it is called.  If not, you need something like this:

```
count.times.map {get_users_online}.flatten
```

Comment: You will get array of arrays too.

Comment: with this solution is must write count.times.map { get_users_online }[0] because i'm getting an array in an array

Comment: That will result in following: [["User1", "User2"], ["User3", "User4"]] => ["User1", "User2"]

Comment: Oops, I forgot that get_users_online is returning an array.  Thanks, and fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is **returning** block

```
  returning(users = Array.new) do |users|
      count.times { users += get_users_online }
  end
```

Comment: Note that returning was removed (not even deprecated) in Rails 3 in favor of #tap.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
def find_users_online(count = 1)
  (1..count).map{ get_users_online }.flatten
end
```

?

Comment: You will get array of arrays.

Comment: @Lavir: depends on what get_users_online returns, no? Adding `.flatten` would, I imagine, fix it if so.

Comment: In the question there were "+=" but not "<<". That implies that "get_users_online()" returns array.

Comment: @Lavir. Ah. Indeed it does. Point taken.

Answer (score 0):

```
get_users_online * count
```

But get_users_online() must return the same value while executing this function.

If this is not your case then use

```
(1..count).map { get_users_online }.reduce(:+)
```

or using Facets:

```
count.of { get_users_online }.sum
```

There is also more interesting way:

```
(1..count).inject(Array.new) { |ignore, users| users + get_users_online }
```